# Temporary fields in Firebird

Tags: triggers, field, firebird, temporary, firebird2.5

Is there temporary fields in Firebird 2.5? When I:

```
INSERT INTO table (..., tmp, ...) (..., val, ...)
```

I need something like this in before-insert trigger:

```
...
new.field1=(SELECT t2.id FROM table2 t2 where t2.field3=new.tmp and t2.field4=new.field5)
new.field2=(SELECT t2.id FROM table2 t2 where t2.field3=new.tmp and t2.field6=new.field7)
...
```

Comment: You might want to look at views with an instead of trigger

Comment: so there is no temporary fields?

Comment: Not in the way you want to use it. Firebird has [global temporary tables](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-table.html#langrefupd25-create-table) and [context variable storage](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-set_context.html). But using columns not part of the table in an insert are not part of the SQL standard, nor of Firebird. My first suggestion is probably the easiest.

Comment: if you need parameters - create stored procedure or execute block

Answer (score 0):

Your code should run correctly. If you want to be sure tmp field is always empty, you can add

```
new.tmp = null;
```

at the end of the trigger.

However, use execute block or a Stored proc, like suggested by @livius is the best way